# Difference between start date and end date with moment js

Tags: angular, datetime, typescript, momentjs

I need to tell you how much time I have for a certain timer, I have the date from which I started the event.

I'm developing with angular 4 Typescript and I use plugin [moment js](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment)

In my html I'm doing so:

```
<div class = "row card-indicator centralize-text">
  {{((locations [indiceMotorist]? trip.createdAt == undefined)? '0': locations [indiceMotorist]? trip.createdAt) | amDifference: today: 'minutes': true}}
</ div>
```

The content that is printed on the screen is:

> -62.444583333333334

My date is in this format, and it comes from my server:

```
created: "2017-11-01T13: 13: 59.015Z"
```

An important point is that I can not use the date of my computer because the server's time and the client pc can be outdated. To solve this problem from time to time I send a location that contains a time also from the server.

```
createdAt: "2017-11-01T14: 22: 23.466Z"
```

I'm thinking of making the end date (in the case I told you about the location) - the start date, in order to get the time that is in course.

I do not know if I can do this with the moment js, but I need to do this, how can I get it?

Is there a plugin that makes it easy, or even a native `javascript` that solves my problem.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: I've seen it myself but I need to do it at runtime, do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Well, at runtime, call the function. It's a JavaScript library. Everything happens at runtime.

Comment: I mean this, would you give me an example of using typescript writing the result in html?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mPM12P5bmsGmzxNCWqsf?p=preview